# total number of threads on nvidia Tesla

Tags: multithreading, nvidia, tesla

What is the total number of threads that can run concurrently on an nvidia Tesla, say S1070.

Comment: The second hit on Google was Wikipedia's page which lists all the stats: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Tesla

Comment: @DeanHarding good idea, though the wiki page doesn't really explain the 32 threads per core. The explanation below is more useful.

Comment: IMHO, the wikipedia article which Dean Harding is referring to is the answer. The total number of CONCURRENTLY RUNNING threads is the same as the total number of the cores, isn't it? How could one core execute 32 threads at the same time?

Answer (score 5):

Combining information from [NVIDIA's product page](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_tesla_s1070_us.html) with [this site](http://www.anandtech.com/print/2849) and an [interesting forum post](http://forums.nvidia.com/lofiversion/index.php?t99082.html), I'd say you're looking at 30720 simultaneous threads on an S1070.  (4 gpus, 240 cores to a gpu, 32 threads to a warp on each core)

Comment: Wow, really? I'm new to GPGPU but I understand it differently. First, are you multiplying threads per warp by number of cores? One core can execute one thread, not one warp. One SM can execute one warp, or am I wrong? Secondly, not all warps are running at the same time, are they? Each SM process one warp and the others are idle, aren't they?